# Number of arbitrary constants in the general solution of a differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following question and answer from the chapter titled [DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lemh203.pdf) of the NCERT textbook

> The number of arbitrary constants in the general solution of a
> differential equation of fourth-order are: **four**

Consider the following function and its differential equation

$$y = e^x$$
$$y'''' -y =0$$

You can observe that Solution of the differential equation is $y = e^x$, which does not contain any constant.

How can I understand the answer to the question given in the textbook?

Comment: You've chosen a very specific equation , to which it turns out three of the constants corresponding to the solution are $0$. If you choose a different differential equation, for which those constants are non-zero, you will see the role played by them.

Comment: Actually, hanugm has chosen a very specific *solution* to that equation. Other solutions are $e^{-x}$, $\sin x$, and $\cos x$, and any linear combination of those four solutions. That's where your four constants come in.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The functions you mention are not solutions to the differential equation.

Comment: @Pierre, wanna bet?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ahhh, missed a $'$!

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear equation of the form $(D^4-1) y = 0$. The general solution can be obtained based on the roots of the characteristic polynomial  $P(D)=D^4-1$, which are $D=\pm 1$ and $D = \pm i$. This leads to
$$
y(x)= c_1 e^x + c_2e^{-x} +c_3 \cos x + c_4 \sin x.
$$

Comment: Like I said, in my comment.